# Magento custom Module - edit form small image preview and delete image checkbox issue

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

[image]

attched screenshot.  magento custom module i am saving image files in  media/finder/images.
   uploaded images are   going in that folders but when i edit the form  small-image-preview appear that is not getting right url.

it is getting media url    http:://demo.com/magento/media/rt.jpg  while it should be 
   http:://demo.com/magento/media/finder/images/rt.jpg .

right now it is showing media url while it should be  media/finder/images. just because getting wrong url edit form showing broken images icon.

how can i get the correct small-image-preview image url?
    here is the image save code in controller. file moves to finder/images/ folder but when i edit moew small image gets media folder url which is not correct.

```
    public function editAction() {
    $id     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $model  = Mage::getModel('finder/finder')->load($id);

    if ($model->getId() || $id == 0) {
        $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model->setData($data);
        }

        Mage::register('finder_data', $model);

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('finder/items');

        $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Manager finder'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Manager finder'));
        $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'));

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('finder/adminhtml_finder_edit'))
            ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('finder/adminhtml_finder_edit_tabs'));

        $this->renderLayout();
    } else {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('finder')->__('Item does not exist'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 1. By default module save your images in media folder.
 2. You have changed the default images saving path to
    media/finder/images
 3. You need to change the path for small-image-preview, need to add
    /finder/images in your path.
```

Try this, if not work please show me your code will explain you more about it.
Thanks,

Comment: You need to change the code in editAction() of your controller.

Comment: This is your saveAction(). this is ok. But when you edit anything at that time edtiAction() will call from your controller. You have to make change in your editAction().

Comment: Edit Action Uploaded Please Check Now.

Comment: "when i edit the form small-image-preview appear" this is in your admin part?

Comment: yes . in admin side edit mode getting such issue.  edit form displaying that small image preview beside the image uploader. image with wrong url. do you know how to remove that thing or fix to have correct url?

Comment: You add or remove fileds from this file.
Banner is namespace
Gallery is my module name.
app/code/local/Banner/Gallery/Block/Adminhtml/Gallery/Edit/Tab/Form.php

Comment: do you know the solution of it? there is only image upload field in tab/form.php